# Why %date% in xml gets replaced by Úte%?

Tags: xml, msbuild

writting an MSBuild script I have found a problem. I'm creating a batch file from the script and I'm writting into it the following sentence:

```
echo %date% - %time%
```

But at the batch file I get:

```
echo Úte% - %time%
```

As far as I know the escape character is & not %. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228186(v=vs.80).aspx

After having a peek around this msdn site says that % is an escape character. When you do %xx is uses xx for the Hex code.

Answer (score 1):

It's being interpreted as %da in the same manner as URL escaping. Why it's doing that, and why it's doing it to the first entry on the line only, I have no idea.

From the link posted in the other answer, try "%25date%25"

Comment: I suppose that it because only the first % has "valid" hexa values after it. Thanks for your response.